# Which is a better design, storing days in database

Tags: mysql, date

I would like to let user see the date about the course. For example, a computer course will held on

```
1/9, 2/9, 3/9.
```

So, how to store these day in the database?
one column the store a string like this:

```
1/9/2011,2/9/2011,3/9/2011
```

or a separate table like this:

```
event_id   date
1          1/9/2011
1          2/9/2011
1          3/9/2011
```

Thank you.

Comment: -1 Every answer except the one you accepted says "separate table". There is a reason for that: normalisation.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

*both methods has it own benefits*

first method will suit for simple data structure,
that's mean your data size could be small,
your project job scope is small,
and you don't wish to spent too many effort on that

*the bad is hard to maintain in long run*

second method will better for normalization
but require more code / JOIN to get the same piece of information
(you can do in one step in the first method)

---

Is **BAD** for date string in `d/m/Y`,
let the presentation language to determine the locale

[ISO format YYYY-MM-DD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) will be the better choice

Comment: `JOIN` to get the same piece of information from the same table? :D I bet the first one requires much more effort than the second one when running a query, or doing any data handling in the DB. There is no benefit on having them in a single column, other than having less records, but that's nothing of a such when compared to the nightmares you will have to go through for querying, updating, etc... About the date format, I don't think any DB will let you insert the date the way you like in a column of `DATE` type.

Comment: @Shef 1. 3 writes is more complicated than one write. 2. Join ... of course, they are user involved 3. I not refer to data type, I refer to date string ...

Comment: 1) Three writes, are far less costly than tons of reads of `WHERE event_date LIKE '%1/9/2011%'`, or the impossible `GROUP BY`, etc..., etc... 2) If you want to fetch data from another table, of course you will have to do a `JOIN`, but in this case (a single table), doesn't have to do with it. After all, you would have to do a  `JOIN` either way. 3) Date string will have to be inserted into the DB, therefore `d/m/Y` is not the syntax a DB would accept.

Comment: @Shef 1. OP did not ask for GROUP, WHERE and whatsoever, he might be looking something easier to implement. 2. The table only consists of two column, does it make sense? (where is the course title, etc)? 3. PRESENTATION!!!! The question does not come with much details the usage, the scope of the project. No point arguing NORMALIZATION is the ONLY BEST.

Comment: -1 The 1st CSV method has no benefit. At all. This is basic relational database stuff. @Shef is correct here and I agree 100% with him. This is a bad answer.

Answer (score 4):

The separate table is the right design, because that's how your schema will be normalized. A table column should hold a single type of value.

[First normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) of database normalization states:

> Every row-and-column intersection contains exactly one value from the
>   applicable domain (and nothing else).

Answer (score 4):

Almost every database under the sun has a `DATE` datatype, which will do exactly this.

Also: use data normalisation: The separate table is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

I would have a table with (at least) 3 columns, using the `date` type for the start and end date

```
event_id start_date end_date
1         1/9/2011  3/9/2011
```

Comment: but some events is special, some may like this: 1/9/2011, 3/9/2011, 5/9,2011

Answer (score 1):

A column should store exactly one value only. Separate table.

As a CSV, how can you

- find course starting 2/9/2001
- order by
- delete 2/9/2001, add 4/9/2011 etc